# Android: 2.3.6 main Thread blocks when I requests to start two services in the Activity.onCreate method

Tags: android, multithreading, service, block, program-entry-point

I'm developing an application which I need to start to background services when the application is started.

Initially I added the startup procedure of the first service on the Application.onCreate() method.

Afterward, I realize that I need to re-start the service if for any reason the user stopped the background thread. Therefore I moved service startup code from the Application.onCreate() to the main Activivity.onResume().

According to the documentation, calling startService() on a already running service has no problem.

Until then, everything was fine. My first background service was implemented just fine. When it starts, it creates a new thread to run the background processing without no major issue.

After implementing the first service, I moved to second one. No problems here. But after implementing it and added the service start call on the Activity.onResume() method.

```
private void startServices() {
    startTrackingService();
    startBacklogService();
}

private void startTrackingService() {
    if (Z10.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "REQUESTING TRACKING SERVICE START");
    }  

    Intent serviceLauncher = new Intent(Main.this, TrackingService.class);
    startService(serviceLauncher);
    if (Z10.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "TRACKING SERVICE START REQUESTED");
    }  
}

private void startBacklogService() {
    if (Z10.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "REQUESTING BACKLOG SERVICE START");
    }  

    Intent serviceLauncher = new Intent(Main.this, BacklogService.class);
    startService(serviceLauncher);
    if (Z10.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "BACKLOG SERVICE START REQUESTED");
    }  
}
```

This code, blocks the main method and the application must be killed.

Trying to debug the application (it is quite difficult without the android source code!!!), I realized that the startService does not really start the service, it simply adds the operation on the Looper queue to be processed.

If, I execute the two startService operation in sequence, the main thread blocks, but if after doing other stuff (UI-related) on the main thread and just then start the second service, it works just fine.

The problem is that I really would need to start both services on the application startup, or restart any of them on the Main activity resume.

Comment: Get rid of the second service. Put its business logic in the first service, so that service does the work of both of your current services.

Comment: Ok, but this is quite crazy that this does not work, ;-(